# How can I calculate large powers manually?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was just wondering if there was nice, pencil and paper approach to calculating large powers with small base values. For example, can someone calculate

$$(1.05)^{15}$$

or numbers of that sort on paper?

Thanks!

Comment: Compute $x_1=1.05^2, x_2=x_1^2, x_3=x_2^2$, then $1.05^{15} = 1.05 x_1 x_2 x_3$.

Comment: Taylor expanstion could be useful, I rember having used it to calculate square roots on paper.

Answer (score 4):

The expansion of your expression is $1.05^{15}=1+15\cdot 0.05+{15 \choose 2}0.05^2+{15 \choose 3} 0.05^3+\dots 0.05^{15}$  The terms get smaller and smaller, so you can quit when you are accurate enough.  This works well when the power times the excess over $1$ of the base is small.  In your case, it is $15 \cdot 0.05=0.75$, which is not so small, so you would need a lot of the terms.

Another approach is to use logs.  $\log (1+x) \approx x$ for $x \ll 1$, so $\log(1.05^{15}) \approx 0.75$ so $1.05^{15} \approx e^{0.75}$  Evaluating $e^{0.75}$ is not so easy, but maybe you know $\log 2 \approx 0.693$, so $e^{0.75}\approx 2\cdot e^{0.057}\approx 2\cdot1.057=2.114$.  This compares with the correct result of about $2.079$, a couple percent off.

Comment: Another example of your second approach working well would be $$100 \times (1.2)^5 \\ = 10^{log(100\times(1.2)^5)} \\ = 10^{log(100)+5log(1.2)} \\ = 10^{2+5(log(12/10))}\\ = 10^{2+5 \times log(12) - 5} \\ = 10^{5 \times (2 \times log 2 + log 3)-3} \\ = 10^{5 \times (0.6+0.477)-3}\\= 10^{5 \times (1.077)-3} = 10^{2.385} \\ = 10^2 \times 10^{0.385} \approx  2.5 \times 10^2 $$

Answer (score 2):

If you want to spend the time working on it, you could use the **[Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)** with $(1+\epsilon)^{15}$. You can even just use fractions, so $$ (1.05)^{15} = \left( \dfrac {105}{100} \right)^{15} = \left( \dfrac {21}{20} \right)^{15} = \dfrac {21^{15}}{20^{15}}. $$

Comment: But then, how would you go about calculating $\frac{21^{15}}{20^{15}}$ I assume you have to change the base, make it the same and work with that?

Comment: Binomial theorem. :P

Answer (score 2):

To compute $x^{15}$ you can proceed with the following computations:
$$x^2=x\cdot x$$
$$x^3=x^2\cdot x$$
$$x^5=x^3\cdot x^2$$
$$x^{10}=x^5\cdot x^5$$
$$x^{15}=x^{10}\cdot x^5$$
This requires $5$ multiplications. I don't know whether this is optimal (in number of multiplications required) or not. I believe there is an algorithm working this way used to compute powers in computers, but I don't know it. Maybe somebody could supply it (if it exists), or elaborate on that?